# Connect to my entire LAN through OpenVPN, QNAP

Tags: vpn, nas, routing, ip, openvpn

I'm trying to set up an OpenVPN server on my QNAP Nas.

My network:

Router: 192.168.0.254
QNAP Nas: 192.168.0.5
Some other computer in LAN: 192.168.0.7
Subnet 255.255.255.0

I've forward port 1194 to 192.168.0.5 in my router. I can connect to the QNAP Nas OpenVPN server from an outside client but can't reach "Some other computer" through that connection.

server.conf

```
# OpenVPN server configuration QNAP NAS  
local 192.168.0.5  
proto udp  
dev tun  
# detect mtu if the connection is slow.  
; mtu-test  
# define mtu, if necessary  
; tun-mtu xyz  
# data compression  
comp-lzo  
# allow, that several clients with the same common name log on  
; duplicate-cn  
# different clients can "see" each other through the tunnel.  
; client-to-client  
# Keepalive  
keepalive 15 120  
# Log files
status /opt/etc/openvpn/log/status.log  
log-append /opt/etc/openvpn/log/openvpn.log  
# Run as daemon (activate, after everything is set up properly)  
daemon  
# Management Interface. Access with "telnet localhost 7505"  
management localhost 7505  
port 1194  
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0  
dh /opt/etc/openvpn/keys/dh1024.pem  
ca /opt/etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt  
cert /opt/etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt  
key /opt/etc/openvpn/keys/server.key  
# route  
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

client.conf

```
# Connect to QNAP OpenVPN Server 
proto udp
dev tun
tls-client
pull
# set mtu, if necessary
; tun-mtu xyz
#
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
# test new in 2.1
remote-cert-tls server
#
comp-lzo

ca "ca.crt"
cert "client.crt"
key "client.key"
remote my.dyndns.com 1194
```

I'm little bit confused about "route...", "push route...", "server..."
Which option should point to which ip-address?

Feels like I'm missing something...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you manage to access server.conf?  It doesn't seem to be available from the QNAP web interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you a short answer: The machine you are trying to reach can't answer your request, because it tries to send it trough its default gateway (your router).
Try putting a static route in your router and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is on the same LAN (192.168.0.0/24) with your QNAP.
1-st Question is what address you get as VPN client ? ( if my interpretation is correct - 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 ). You must add route on you computer to reach 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 by 192.168.0.5 (cuz you QNAP and computer are in the same lan.